# NLog unexpectedly writing to log with lower level restriction - log level being ignored

Tags: nlog

I'm confused by NLog logging level fallbacks. I have this set of rules:

```
  <rules>
      <!-- Send Microsoft into a black hole to hide their logs -->
      <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Warn" final="true" />
      <logger name="commands" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logger" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logger" />
    <logger name="exception" minlevel="Error" writeTo="publisher" final="true" />
  </rules>
```

What I expect to happen is that anything with a logger name of "commands" will only be logged at Info level or above. Any other logger name will be logged regardless.

What's happening is that when I get the logger for "commands" and I check its properties every log level is enabled, so if I provide a log level of Debug, then it's still logged. From what I understand, this shouldn't be the case.

I think this is something to do with my fallback logger (the name="*") I believe the "final=true" on the "commmand" logger should any further logging checks.

This is running in .net core

Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: You can read about logging-rules here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules . They are evaluated from top to bottom, and final will stop further evaluation. But when using minLevel="Info" with final="true" then it will only stop the logevents with that loglevel (or higher like Warn+Error). Will not stop LogEvents with LogLevel.Trace or Debug from flowing down to the next rules that has minLevel="Trace".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
  <rules>
    <!-- Send Microsoft into a black hole to hide their logs -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Warn" final="true" />
    <logger name="commands" maxLevel="Debug" final="true" />

    <logger name="commands" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logger" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logger" />
    <logger name="exception" minlevel="Error" writeTo="publisher" final="true" />
  </rules>
```